# AutoHotKey - MsgBox (Else/If)

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

How can I continue with the scripting, inside the messagebox, if example "Yes" is pressed?

```
 ;Print FIA Forside.
 MsgBox, 4, Print Forside?, Vil du printe en forside til denne sending? (press Yes or No
IfMsgBox Yes

 ;Find the shipment in EDI - Open the excel file and print it!
  Click 2206,581
  Click 1435,326
  Send {Ctrl Down}c{Ctrl Up}
  Click 1886,1044


else
    MsgBox You pressed No.
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: ELSE with no matching IF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use curly-brackets to wrap your code. Like this:

```
;Print FIA Forside.
MsgBox, 4, Print Forside?, Vil du printe en forside til denne sending? (press Yes or No)
IfMsgBox Yes
{
    msgBox, You pressed yes!
    ; Put more code here
} 
else 
{
    msgBox, You pressed no!
}
```